# Serilog: How to exclude several sources

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I want to have several log files and I am trying to find a way to exclude several sources. This is my code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire"))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile("Logs/hangfire-{Date}.txt"))
    )
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Hangfire"))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile("Logs/main-{Date}.txt"))
    )
    .CreateLogger();
```

As you can see I have sub loggers: first collects hangfire logs only, second one all logs except of hangfire. But, I want to add another excluding filter, for examle, I want to exclude hangfire and `IMyClass` logs. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Matching.FromSource()` return a function from `LogEvent` to `bool`. You can take advantage of that to create two filter functions:

```
var hangfire = Matching.FromSource("Hangfire");
var myClass = Matching.FromSource("MyClass");
```

And then call them inline:

```
.WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByExcluding(le => myClass(le) || hangfire(le))
    .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile("Logs/main-{Date}.txt"))
)
```